# Using RGB10_A2_UI format in glRenderBufferStorage()

Tags: opengl, opengl-3, fbo

I am using FBO and rendering to a texture. Here's my code :

```
GLuint FramebufferName = 0;

glGenFramebuffers(1, &FramebufferName);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FramebufferName);

GLuint renderedTexture;

glGenTextures(1, &renderedTexture);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderedTexture);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGB10_A2UI,256,256,0,GL_RGBA_INTEGER,GL_UNSIGNED_INT_10_10_10_2,0);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

GLuint color_buffer;

glGenRenderbuffers(1, &color_buffer);

glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, color_buffer);

glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGB10_A2UI, 256, 256);

glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, color_buffer);

glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,renderedTexture, 0);

GLenum DrawBuffers[2] = {GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0};
glDrawBuffers(1, DrawBuffers);

GLuint textureId;

LoadImage(textureId); // Loads texture data into textureId

Render(); // Renders textureId onto FramebufferName

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0); // Bind default FBO

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderedTexture); //Render using renderedTexture

glDrawArrays (GL_TRIANGLE_FAN,0, 4);
```

The output is incorrect. The image is not rendered correctly. If I use format GL_RGBA instead of GL_RGB10_A2UI everything goes fine. The FBO is GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE ,no issues there. Am I doing something wrong here ?

My fragment shader for GL_RGB10_A2UI is :

```
in vec2 texcoord;

uniform usampler2D basetexture;

out vec4 Color;

void main(void)
{
    uvec4 IntColor =  texture(basetexture, texcoord);

    Color = vec4(IntColor.rgb, 1023.0) / 1023.0;

}
```

For GL_RGBA I am not doing normalization in shader.

Comment: You've said before that "*I meant to use GL_RGB10_A2UI and not GL_RGB10_A2.*". Why? What do you need `GL_RGB10_A2UI` for? Because you don't really seem to understand the difference between a "texture that has integers" and a "texture that has *normalized* integers". And if you don't understand that difference, you probably don't have a reason for wanting to write to an integral texture.

Comment: The code you added only seems to confirm that you're not clear on how normalized textures work. You *don't do the normalization yourself*. If you want to use normalized integers in RGB10_A2, then you *don't* want the `UI` version. It's that simple.

Answer (score 1):

> If I use format GL_RGBA instead of GL_RGB10_A2UI everything goes fine.

If that's true, then it means your shader is *not writing integers*.

We've discussed this before, but you don't really seem to understand something. An integer texture is a *very different thing* from a floating-point texture or a normalized integer texture.

There is no circumstance where a `GL_RGBA8` texture *and* a `GL_RGB10_A2UI` texture would both work with the same code. The same shader cannot read from a texture that could be normalized or integral texture. The same shader cannot *write to* a buffer that could be normalized or integral. The same pixel transfer code cannot write to or read from an image that could be normalized or integral. They are in every way different entities, which require different parameters to access them.

Furthermore, even if a shader *could* write to either one, what would it be writing? Integer textures take *integers*; if you attempt to stick a floating-point value on the range [0, 1] into an integer, it will either come out as 0 or 1. And if you try to put an integer in the [0, 1] range, you will get 0 if your integer was zero, and 1 otherwise. So whatever your fragment shader is doing is very confused.

Odds are very good that you really should be using `GL_RGB10_A2`, despite your belief that you really did mean to use `GL_RGB10_A2UI`. If you really meant to be writing integers, your shader would be writing integers and not floats, and therefore your shader would not have "worked" with `GL_RGBA8`.

However, if you really, *truly* want to use an unsigned *integral* texture, and you really, *truly* understand what that means and how it is different from `GL_RGB10_A2`, then here are the things you have to do:

- Any fragment shader that intends to write to an integer texture must write to an integer *output variable*. And the signed/unsigned state of that output must match the destination image's signed/unsigned format. So for your `GL_RGB10_A2UI`, an unsigned integer format, you must be writing to a `uvec4`. You should be writing integers to this value, not floating-point values.
- Any shader that intends to read from an integer texture must use an [integer sampler uniform](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sampler_%28GLSL%29#Sampler_types). And that sampler uniform must match the signed/unsigned format of the image. So for your `GL_RGB10_A2UI`, you must
- Pixel transfer operations must explicit use the `_INTEGER` pixel transfer formats.

Comment: I am not using same fragment shader for GL_RGB10_A2UI and GL_RGBA. Please read the edit.Also I am doing corresponding changes in GL source code as well. I am not getting how can I write to uvec4 when my format is GL_RGB10_A2UI ?

Comment: The type is GL_UNSIGNED_INT_10_10_10_2, so if I have to write uvec4 in fragment shader how can we do normalization ?

Comment: @maverick9888: "*how can we do normalization*" If you wanted a normalized format, you should be using a *normalized format*. You know, like `GL_RGB10_A2`. It is a normalized, unsigned integer format. It does *all the work for you*.

Comment: @maverick9888 *"I am not using same fragment shader for GL_RGB10_A2UI and GL_RGBA. Please read the edit."* - And exactly that edit shows that you indeed try to write a `vec4` (floating point vector) into an unsignd integer texture, whereas this answer has made it perfectly clear that *this won't work* and *you have to use an unsigned integer output*, `out uvec4 Color` in your case. If you do normalization or not in the shader is completely irrelevant to the technical problem (though it might point to some conceptual misunderstanding of how integer textures work).

Comment: @Nicol Bolas I have a question. What if the fragment shader has two samplers ,one which is unsigned int and other a floating point ? What should we output from shader ?
Also NVidia driver did not give any trouble using above fragment shader.

Comment: @maverick9888: What you use to compute a number does not matter to where you use that number. The value(s) you write from a fragment shader must match the image(s) you are *writing* to, not whatever you happened to read from. Also, you never answered my question above about why you need to manually do what OpenGL will do *automatically* if you just let OpenGL do it. You are making something that's really quite simple into something much more complicated.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas My job is to make sure that driver is not lying to us !
So there is actually particularly no reason why I am using RGB10_A2UI

Comment: @maverick9888 *"My job is to make sure that driver is not lying to us!"* - But making wrong usage doesn't help in any way. The answer has repeatly pointed out what you're doing wrong (normalizing where you shouldn't, writing to floating point output variable). You cannot expect the driver to work correct if *you yourself do it wrong*.